# How populate XmlNodeList with all the children of a node with the same name?

Tags: .net, xml, xmlnode, xmlnodelist

Given a [XmlNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.aspx) containing the following XML fragment, how do I fill XmlNodeList with book nodes?

XMLNode nodeLibrary contains:

```
<library>
  <book>
      <title>Three Little Pigs</title>
  </book>
  <book>
      <title>Batman</title>
  </book>
  <address>123 Main St.</address>
  <phone>111-111-1111</phone>
</library>
```

This should be really easy but I can't figure it out:

A) Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Xml.XmlElement' to 'System.Xml.XmlNodeList':

XmlNodeList books = nodeLibrary["book"];

I guess the method property shortcut above assumes there's a SINGLE child named book, not multiple!

B) XmlNode doesn't have a GetChildren() method:

XmlNodeList books = nodeLibrary.GetChildren("book");

C) XmlNode's [ChildNodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.childnodes.aspx) property gets ALL children, not just book nodes.

D) I tried using SelectNodes() method but the root is the larger document, not the library fragment in the current XmlNode that was selected from a larger document earlier using SelectNodes.

Any ideas?
Pete

Comment: Does it have to be a `XmlNodeList`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SelectNodes, and in the XPath query pass a '.' to start searching from that node:

```
public class StackOverflow_6618097
{
    const string XML = @"<buildings>
 <library>
  <book>
   <title>Three Little Pigs</title>
  </book>
  <book>
   <title>Batman</title>
  </book>
  <address>123 Main St.</address>
  <phone>111-111-1111</phone>
  <hidden>
   <book>
    <title>The Hidden Treasure</title>
   </book>
  </hidden>
 </library>
 <bookstore>
  <book>
   <title>Cat in the Hat</title>
  </book>
 </bookstore>
</buildings>";

    public static void Test()
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(XML);
        XmlNode libraryNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//library");
        XmlNodeList libraryBooks = libraryNode.SelectNodes(".//book");
        Console.WriteLine("Books: {0}", libraryBooks.Count);
        foreach (XmlNode node in libraryBooks)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(node.OuterXml);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably best to use `./book` to filter direct children instead of all descendants.

Comment: Right, I added the "Hidden Treasure" example to show that the code will return all the descendants; thanks for adding this extra information.